# First fadein doesn't seem to work sometimes (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a little animated story. The issue is that sometimes the first fadein doesn't fire. This only seems to happen sometimes and in certain situations that I can't seem to figure out. As far as I can tell it is cache related.

Here is the code for a page that has the issue often:

```
//waits until document is open

$(window).load(function() {

    //if it's night time when you read this it displays a night time photo, if it's day time it's a day time photo... don't know how many people might notice

    if (time === "night"){
        $.backstretch("downtownnight.jpg");

        //makes the font white with a black outline so you can read it easily on the night photo
        $("#content").css("color","#FFFFFF");
        $("#content").css("text-shadow","1px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 1px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000");

    }
    else {
        $.backstretch("downtownday.jpg");

        $("#content").css("text-shadow","1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff, 0 1px 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff"); }
});


$(document).ready(function(){

    //fades in the first line of text

    $("#partFive").fadeIn(2000)

    setTimeout(function () {

        //fades in the second line of text

        $("#partFive").fadeOut(2000)

        setTimeout(function () {


            $("#awesome").fadeIn(3000)

            setTimeout(function () {


                $("#awesome").fadeOut(2000)

                setTimeout(function () {


                    $("#awesome").fadeOut(1000)

                    setTimeout(function () {


                        $("#partSix").fadeIn(2000)


                    }, 2000);

                }, 2000);

            }, 2000);

        }, 2000);

    }, 2000);

});
```

I found this on stack overflow to stop caching issues but it doesn't seem to help

```
<!-- ignores any cache you might have! -->

<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

You can find the test version of the site here: http://www.chilltoday.com/test/

HTML was requested, Here it is in pastebin: http://pastebin.com/XyM9si2c

Comment: Can you show HTML code

Comment: not working as in #partFive did not show at the beginning?

Answer (score -1):

If you want the fadeIn effect, you need to make sure that #partFive is hidden in the beginning  before calling fadeIn().

I don't see anything wrong with your code. But instead, I added "display:none;" to all the divs you need fadeIn() and it seems to work for me.

```
#partFive, #awesome, #partSix {
    display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EYWML/

Comment: Hi, I do have that div set as 'hidden' from the get go. The issue is that it doesn't work 'sometimes' which I know is annoying. In general it works, but it seems to not fade in the first text in random scenarious.

Comment: Not fade in as in it just shows without the animation? or it does not show at all?

Comment: It doesn't fade in at all. Nothing shows it stays as 'hidden' for some reason.

Comment: Have you tried wrap your whole execution with a delay timer (like 0.5 seconds)? Sometimes timing issue matters.